# Programmatically find identical areas on 2 photos

Tags: c#, image, find

I have 2 identical cameras which are placed in one line in 20 cm between each other. So i take 2 photos:

Sorry i cant upload photos here due of restrictions

Photos from cameras and image for better understanding:
http://oi62.tinypic.com/2lkv682.jpg

How can i find all identical areas(not only toy car, it is for example only) on two photos? Maybe is there is a good algorithm or maybe library for C# or C++?

Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to find similarities on two photos ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232821/find-differences-between-images

Comment: [link]http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/bitmap/article.php/c4885/Finding-Similarity-Between-Images.htm

Comment: @NicholeGrace the problem is, there is no specific object which i want to find, i need to compare 2 photos, find all objects that are similar in two photos, to understand where objects are moved

Comment: i think this might be relevant here:http://xkcd.com/1425/

Comment: I doubt that there is even a single pixel identical in those two images. Don't try to tackle this on your own; I'm sure there are libraries that can help, but gettin those images to be better is the first thing I'd recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Opencv (c++) or emgucv (c#) is probably what you are looking for. There are plenty examples available on how to compare images and object recognition.

Comment: the problem is, there is no specific object which i want to find, i need to compare 2 photos, find all objects that are similar in two photos, to understand where objects are moved

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExhaustiveTemplateMatching](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/17494328-ef0c-dc83-1bc3-907b7b75039f.htm) from AForge.NET Framework

```
ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching (0.9f);
TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage(image1, image2);
```

The [TemplateMatch](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/1d89c9a9-eff4-5bea-2784-f84c150f955a.htm) class has the properties Similarity and Rectangle that you can use to find the identical areas on two photos.

Comment: Thanks! But this function search template in source image, this doesn't search for similar areas on two photos